# Apply javascript function on all data in table (which data is derived with python)

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I am applying show/hide function on two columns of my table,
but only the first row is shown and I think it’s because of the for in python, what can I do?

here's the codes:

html:

```
<ul class="w3-ul">
  <tr>
    <th onclick="sortTable(0)"> one </th>
    <th id="wtitle" class="word_title" onclick="sortTable(6)"> seven </th>
    <th id="gtitle" class="sentence_title" onclick="sortTable(7)"> eight </th>
  </tr>
    {% for item in object_list %}
  <tr>
     <td>{{ item.one }}</td>
     <td id="wcolumn" class="word_column"> {{ item.seven }}</div></td>
     <td id="gcolumn" class="sentence_column">{{ item.eight }}</td>
  </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Css:

```
  .word_title, .sentence_title, word_column, sentence_column{
    display: none;
    width:100px;
  }
  .y, .x, .show{
    width:100px;
    z-index:100;
  }
```

Javascript:

```
  function showcolumns()
  {
      document.getElementById('wtitle').setAttribute("class", "y");
      document.getElementById('wcolumn').setAttribute("class", "y");
      document.getElementById('gtitle').setAttribute("class", "y");
      document.getElementById('gcolumn').setAttribute("class", "y");
  }
```

Comment: You're creating duplicate IDs in your loop, which results in invalid markup. This is what is responsible for `document.getElementById` only returning the first response.

Comment: I know, it's because of the loop, but how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't add IDs during the loop, and use `document.getElementByClassName` instead, or better yet, `this` (if you want to target based on the row clicked).

Comment: Do you really want to set the `class` attribute? That will remove the existing class and replace it with `y`. It would be better to use `.classList.add("y")`.